# "Failed to request ThreadStore" - WinDbg debugging live process

Tags: .net-4.0, windbg, sos

I am debugging the live process (not dump) of PresentationHost.exe. It used to works fine, but suddenly few days ago I get the above error message. !Threads, !pe, virtually all SOS command doesn't work.

All I remember is that I installed Visual Studio 2010 and .NET framework 4.0 before I'm getting that error. Is it related?

**UPDATE:**

I myself can not reproduce the problem I was having. Probably I was debugging 32 bit process with 64 bit debugger, or .NET 4 process with .NET 2.0 SOS, or vice versa, or combination of both bitness and DLL version.

Apologize that this question may not valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using WinDbg/SOS to debug managed->native callstack.  I get "Failed to request ThreadStore"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478802/using-windbg-sos-to-debug-managed-native-callstack-i-get-failed-to-request-th)

Comment: No it is different. The article you mention is debugging on minidump file, while I am debugging live process

Answer (score 0):

When are you trying to issue the command?
This error is quite common when attempting to issue SOS commands before the CLR was fully loaded.
You could attempt to break right after the CLR had finished its initialization procedure. In order to break at that point, you could place a breakpoint in the following manner: `bp clr!EEStartup "gu"`. This will cause the debugger to break on the `EEStartup` function, and continue execution until the function completes.
When the debugger breaks on that breakpoint, you should be able to issue your SOS commands.

Comment: I was issuing the command after my application loaded, so I believe the CLR has been loaded. Thanks for the tips anyway.